# C#: Referencing Classes by a Variable

Tags: c#, variables, syntax

I'm trying to get the hang of using variables in C#, but have hit a roadblock.  The following doesn't work.

```
public static void SetBG(string s)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.s;
}
```

A very simple method that should set the console's background color according to what the programmer sent through the `s` variable.  If I used `SetBG("Red");`, it should go through, but it doesn't.  This is because `System.ConsoleColor' does not contain a definition for 's'`.

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the correct way to do this, and it looks like there are two main concepts you're having trouble with, and understanding them will help you do this correctly.

Firstly, `s` is a variable in your current class. `ConsoleColor.s` would refer to the `s` variable in the `ConsoleColor` class (it does not have one, hence your error). This is called [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29), or [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), and allows us to reuse common words/names without conflict.

Secondly, your code will be compiled before it is run, and `ConsoleColor.s` (assuming there was such a thing) would no longer say `ConsoleColor.s`. Instead, it would point to a place in memory where a value is stored representing "s". The `s` being passed to your method will be a string, such as "Red" or "Blue". There is no connection between such a string and a slot in memory for a differnt object to store it's values.

To do what you are trying to do, you need to take the name of the color and translate it into a color. One way to do this would be with a series of `if`/`else` statements checking the contents of the string and assigning the appropriate color if it matches a color name.
Fortunately, there is an easier way. You can simply parse the string into a `ConsoleColor`!

Following [the example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) you can do this:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), s);
```

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed reply! However, my compiler is giving me the error: `The name 'Color' does not exist in the current context` which I'm guessing is a library issue. What libraries do I need to include? So far I have: `using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text;`EDIT: Sorry, linebreaks don't work in comments.

Comment: You can find `Color` in the `System.Drawing` namespace

Comment: It says 'Drawing is not found in the System namespac, are you missing an assembly reference?'.  This is a Console application, so I'd assume that graphics libraries aren't included by default.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you can't convert from a `Color` to a `ConsoleColor`.  The best you could do would be to call `Color.FromName(s).ToKnownColor()` and try to match that up to a `ConsoleColor` value...or, as demonstrated by other answers, just parse `s` as a `ConsoleColor` and you'll have the correct type to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof (ConsoleColor), s);
```

Answer (score 2):

ConsoleColor is an enum.  You'll have to cast `s`.

```
public static void SetBG(string s){
   Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because ConsoleColor is an enumeration, try

```
 Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), s);
```

You should consider handling if the string is not valid (e.g. s="Ship") with something like this

```
 ConsoleColor colorValue;
 if (Enum.TryParse(s, out colorValue))
 {        
     Console.BackgroundColor = colorValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ConsoleColor colour;
if (ConsoleColor.TryParse(s, out colour))
{
   Console.BackgroundColor = colour;
}
```

Comment: I almost downvoted this thinking it wouldn't even compile, but it does work so I'll upvote.  At first I thought "There is no `TryParse` method defined on the `ConsoleColor` enumeration!", but actually there is.  Since the base class of `ConsoleColor` is `Enum`, you can call the static `Enum.TryParse` method through either the base class or the child class.  This might be a confusing way to call that method (it tripped me up, anyways), but it does work.  Whoever did downvote this answer should try the code themselves.

Comment: I downvoted for the same reason.  And just tried it too.  And now it's locked.  Sorry. If the answer gets edited and I get unlocked, I'll change it.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to everyone else's use of the [`Enum.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.parse.aspx), as of .NET 4.0 you can use the [`Enum.TryParse` generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee835389.aspx) to better handle invalid values:

```
public static void SetBG(string s)
{
    ConsoleColor color;

    if (!Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(s, out color))
        throw new ArgumentException("s");

    Console.BackgroundColor = color;
}
```